# C++ function specialization for equal parameters

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, overloading, template-specialization

I, like so many others, am writing a linear algebra library for my personal use. In doing so, I'm trying to learn more about programming with templates in C++. I have a class, which goes something like

```
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M = N>
class Matrix
{
    ...
}
```

Now, there are certain operations that I would like to restrict to square matrices (determinant, for example). But when I try to add:

```
T Determinant<T,N,N>();
```

It fails to compile, with the error being "Missing ';' before '<'". I've tried adding another template above the determinant call, without any success. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `N` is not a template parameter name, at the point that you are defining it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot specialize a function for specific template parameters like that, you have to do the whole class.  Since you don't want to re-code the entire thing, you probably want to use inheritance.

```
//shared code
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class BaseMatrix
{
    //existing code
};

// non-square general case
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M=N>
class Matrix : public BaseMatrix<T,N,M>
{
    //forwarding headers
    Matrix (const Matrix<T,N,M>& b) : BaseMatrix<T,N,M>(b) {}
};

//square matrix specialization
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Matrix : public BaseMatrix<T,N,N>
{
    //forwarding headers
    Matrix (const Matrix<T,N,M>& b) : BaseMatrix<T,N,M>(b) {}
    T Determinant();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now, there are certain operations that I would like to restrict to square matrices (determinant, for example).

Do you mean a free function like this:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t N >
T determinant( Matrix< T, N, N > const& m ){ ... }
```

or do you mean it as class members? If you need a class member, then you are better of moving all the common functionality to a base class, and using template specialization on `Matrix` to include the extra functionality for square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I support the base class idea. Have a Matrix class, and a SquareMatrix subclass. Declare the Determinant method in the SquareMatrix class and safely assume that the matrix is square without having to deal with templates. The determinant method will be simpler and so will be the code that calls it.

Answer (score -4):

You have to declare a variable like this: `Matrix<float, 10, 10> myMatrix;`.